# First order wave function in adiabatic approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, time-evolution, adiabatic

If the Hamiltonian is slowly varying in time and suppose the initial state is the n-th eigenstate of the initial Hamiltonian H(0), the adiabatic theorem says that the state will still on the n-th eigenstate of the Hamiltonian H(t) during the evolution, accumulating a dynamic phase and geometric phase.

The above theorem can be shown by considering only the zero-th order wave function, however, **what does the first order wave function looks like?**

i.e. when we consider the the transition between the different energy levels, just like in the perturbation method in the time independent perturbation theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question is helps to start with the adiabatic portion.

Consider a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}\left(\mathbf{P}\right)$, where $\mathbf{P}(t)$ is some time-varying *parameter vector*. This Hamiltonian has a set of time-dependent eigenstates $|n\left(t\right)\rangle$ with corresponding energies $E_n\left(t\right)$ which evolve via the Schrodinger's equation $i\hbar \partial_t|\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle = \hat{H}\left(t\right)|\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle$.

If $\mathbf{P}\left(t\right)$ is constant in time and the system starts out in one of the eigenstates $|n\left(0\right)\rangle$ at $t = 0$, the state accumulates a phase factor with time so that $|\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle = e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}|n\left(0\right)\rangle$.

For finite $\partial_t\mathbf{P}\left(t\right)$, the eigenstates and eigenvalues change in time. Still, let us set $|\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle = c_n(t)|n\left(t\right)\rangle$. Putting this into the Schrodinger's equation gives

\begin{equation}
 i\hbar\partial_t \left[ c_n(t)|n\left(t\right)\rangle\right] = E_n\left(t\right)c_n(t)|n\left(t\right)\rangle\,.
\end{equation}

Taking the time derivative of the left-hand side and then applying $\langle n\left(t\right)|$ to both sides, we get

\begin{equation}
 \dot{c}_n\left(t\right) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}c_n\left(t\right)E_n\left(t\right) -c_n\left(t\right)\langle n\left(t\right)|\dot{n}\left(t\right)\rangle  \,.
\end{equation}

This differential equation can be solved using the separation of variables:

\begin{equation}
 c_n\left(t\right) = \exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t E_n\left(t'\right)dt' - \int_0^t\langle n\left(t'\right)|\dot{n}\left(t'\right)\rangle dt'\right]\,.
\end{equation}

It is possible to use the chain-rule to rewrite the second integrand as $\langle n\left(t'\right)|\dot{n}\left(t'\right)\rangle = \langle n\left(\mathbf{P}\right)|\nabla_\mathbf{P}n\left(\mathbf{P}\right)\rangle\cdot \dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t'\right)$, where $\nabla_\mathbf{P}$ is the gradient in $\mathbf{P}$ space. Since $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t'\right)dt' = d\mathbf{P}$, we have

\begin{equation}
 c_n\left(t\right) =e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t E_n\left(t'\right)dt'}e^{i\int_{\mathbf{P}_i}^{\mathbf{P}_f}\mathcal{A}_n\cdot d\mathbf{P}}\,,
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{P}_i = \mathbf{P}_i\left(0\right)$, $\mathbf{P}_f = \mathbf{P}\left(t\right)$, and $\mathcal{A}_n = i\langle n\left(\mathbf{P}\right)|\nabla_\mathbf{P}n\left(\mathbf{P}\right)\rangle$.

So, here you have the dynamic and the geometric (Berry) phase that you mentioned.

Up to now, we assumed that the system remains in the same eigenstate by asserting that the Hamiltonian changes very slowly and the system is always in the $n$th eigenstate. Let us now relax this assumption and write $|n\left(t\right)\rangle \rightarrow |n\left(t\right)\rangle + f\left(\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\right)|\delta n\left(t\right)\rangle$, where $f\left(\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\right)$ is some function. For $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\rightarrow 0$, the second term vanishes as we restore the adiabatic regime. This means that, to the leading order, $f\left(\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\right)$ is linear in $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)$. By keeping only this linear term and absorbing it into the correction, we write the corrected state $|n\left(t\right)\rangle \rightarrow |n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta \left(t\right)\rangle$, where $|\delta \left(t\right)\rangle$ is linear in $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)$.

Above, we showed that the phase of the state does not depend on the rate of change of $\mathbf{P}$. So, we keep $c_n\left(t\right)$ for the state with the correction. Putting $c_n\left(t\right)\left[|n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta \left(t\right)\rangle\right]$ into the Schrodinger's equation and dividing by $c_n\left(t\right)$ yields

\begin{align}
   i\hbar\left\{\left( -\frac{i}{\hbar}E_n\left(t\right)+i\mathcal{A}_n\left(t\right) \cdot \dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right) \right) \left[|n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle\right] 
   + 
   \dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\cdot \nabla_\mathbf{P} \left[|n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle\right]\right\}
  &=
  \hat{H}\left(t\right)\left[|n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle\right]\,,
\end{align}

where we have replaced the time derivative acting on $|n\left(t\right)\rangle + |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle$ by $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\cdot \nabla_\mathbf{P}$.

There are a few simplifications we make here. First, the $E_n\left(t\right)|n\left(t\right)\rangle$ term on the left gets cancelled by $\hat{H}\left(t\right)|n\left(t\right)\rangle$ on the right. Also, $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right) |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle$ and $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right) \cdot \nabla_\mathbf{P}|\delta\left(t\right)\rangle$ are quadratic in $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)$, so we eliminate them. The remaining terms are

\begin{align}
  i \hbar\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\cdot \left[
   i \mathcal{A}_n\left(t\right)  
    +
     \nabla_\mathbf{P} \right]
     |n\left(t\right)\rangle
  &=
  \left[\hat{H}\left(t\right) - E_n \left(t\right)\right]|\delta\left(t\right)\rangle \,.
 \end{align}

Finally, we apply $\langle m\left(t\right)|$ to both sides of this expression to get

\begin{equation}
 |\delta\left(t\right)\rangle = i\hbar 
 \sum_{m\neq n}|m\left(t\right)\rangle\frac{\langle m\left(t\right) |\partial_t n\left(t\right)\rangle }{E_m\left(t\right)-E_n\left(t\right)}\,,
 \label{eqn:delta_3}
\end{equation}

where we have recombined $\dot{\mathbf{P}}\left(t\right)\cdot \nabla_\mathbf{P}$ into $\partial_t$.

Using $\langle m\left(t\right)|\partial_t \left[\hat{H}\left(t\right)|n\left(t\right)\rangle\right] = \langle m\left(t\right)|\partial_t\hat{H}\left(t\right) |n\left(t\right)\rangle + \langle m\left(t\right)|E_m\left(t\right)|\partial_tn\left(t\right)\rangle = E_n\left(t\right)\langle m\left(t\right)|\partial_t n\left(t\right)\rangle$, we write the time-dependent state as

\begin{equation}
 |\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle =c_n\left(t\right)\left[|n\left(t\right)\rangle 
 -
 i\hbar 
 \sum_{m\neq n}|m\left(t\right)\rangle\frac{\langle m\left(t\right) |\partial_t \hat{H}\left(t\right)|n\left(t\right)\rangle }{\left[E_m\left(t\right)-E_n\left(t\right)\right]^2}\right]
 \,.
\end{equation}

Comment: $c_n(t)$ is absorbed into $|n(t)>$ or dropped completely in your last formula? Is it justified in time dependent S.E.

Comment: Does $\delta n(t)$ has $n(t)$ component? I only see you discuss $m \neq n$ case. I know we can absorb that part in the original $n(t)$, but that means the coefficient of the second term of last equation should also change. Maybe your logic is considering it as a second order $\dot{P}(t)$ effect.

Comment: I reinstated the $c_n(t)$. In principle, if you are not looking for interference effects and only care about the expectation value, $c_n(t)$ doesn't play a role. For the correction, there is no $m = n$ case. This would cause the denominator to go to zero and the expression to diverge. The absence of $n$ is the standard result in perturbation theory (like the 1st order correction in time-independent systems)

Comment: Diverge in denominator is not the excuse.

Comment: Your final answer does not satisfy the initial condition $|\psi(0)\rangle = |n(0)\rangle$.

Comment: That's not the initial condition. We are showing that because of the changing Hamiltonian the system is not in any of its temporary eigenstates $n\left(t\right)\rangle$. Take a look at the paragraph starting with "Up to now..."

Comment: @IcyOtter I mean it's understandable that it won't be in any of eigenstates after $t>0$, but as far as I can understand, it doesn't quite answer Hosein's question why the initial condition is now different. Indeed, what the adiabatic theorem is telling us is that we're solving the Schrodinger equation for initial condition $|\psi(0)\rangle =|n(0)\rangle$ but with the case where $H(t)$ is slowly varying, e.g., $H(t)=H(t/\tau)$ and we take $\tau \to \infty$.

Comment: @AndrewYuan I see what you're saying. OK, take a look at the second term in the final answer. How does H(t) START to vary in time? Is the variation switched on slowly so that the derivative vanishes at t =0? then dH/dt -> 0 and we go back to |Psi(0)> = c(0) |n(0)>. If the variation is NOT switched on with a vanishing derivative, there is a  "kick" at t = 0 that creates a discontinuity.

Comment: @IcyOtter That makes sense. Thx.

Comment: @AndrewYuan Thank you for engaging with the discussion :)! It's super helpful to think more deeply about one's own answers

Comment: @IcyOtter So I thought about it more deeply, and I think the initial condition is problem is a little more subtle. Indeed, the adiabatic theorem is solving the Schrodinger equation for $H(t) = \tilde{H}(t/\tau)$ with *exact* initial condition $\psi(t=0)=|0\rangle$, where eventually we take the adiabatic time scale $\tau \to \infty$. Let us write $0\le s=t/\tau \le 1$ and $\psi_\tau (s) = \psi(t)$ be the solution of the Schrodinger equation with initial condition $\psi(t=0)=|0\rangle$.

Comment: Therefore, if you were to calculate $\psi_\tau (1)=\psi(\tau)$ to the $n$th order of $1/\tau$, we would require that $\psi_\tau (1) = \text{some expression} +O(1/\tau^{n+1})$ and that $\psi_\tau(0)= |0\rangle$ *exactly*. If $\psi_\tau(s)$ were to satisfy the initial condition only up to $O(1/\tau)$, then I think I can modify the expression by any constant $O(1/\tau)$. I actually asked a similar question here (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651629/rigorous-hall-conductance) where the rigorous proof from Kato's paper is equal to your solution up to a $O(1/\tau)$

Comment: @AndrewYuan you are right: the solution above gives just the first order correction. In fact, you can see that something is a little strange if you try to normalise the state. Taking the inner product of $|\Psi\rangle$ with itself, you will see that in addition to $\langle n|n\rangle$ (which, for normalised $n$ is 1), we have a term that's proportional to $(\partial_t H)^2$. 
I'll take a look at the Kato paper