# Rigorous Hall conductance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, quantum-hall-effect

I have been trying to understand the rigorous argument for calculating the hall conductance by averaging over two fluxes by reading this paper {1}. I think I understand the entire derivation, except for how the authors derived Eq. (3). In their footnote (13), they claim they need to apply the adiabatic theorem not just to the zeroth order (an adiabatic phase change of the eigenstate, i.e., $\Psi^\text{ad} (s) \propto |s\rangle$ where $|s\rangle$ is the non-degenerate eigenstate of $H(s)$), but to the first order. More specifically, if we ignore the dynamical phase change, i.e., set eigenvalue $\lambda(s)=0$, then what the footnote claims seems to be that
$$
\Psi_\tau(s)= \left[1  -\frac{1}{i\tau} S(s)^2 H'(s) +O(\tau^{-2})\right] \Psi^\text{ad}(s)
$$
Where $t= s\tau$ and we eventually take $\tau  \to \infty$ to approach to adiabatic limit. Here, I'm using Kato's {2} original notation.

*However*, I don't quite understand where this first order term comes from. Indeed, I read through Kato's original paper on the rigorous proof of the adiabatic theorem {2}, and I think the first order approximation comes from Eq. (28) in {2}, but if that's so, then the equation should imply rather
$$
V_\tau(s)\left[E(0) - \frac{1}{i\tau} S(0) W'(0) \right] - \left[1 -\frac{1}{i\tau} S(s) E'(s) \right] W(s) =O(\tau^{-2})
$$
Where I'm using Kato's original notation. It's not too hard to check that $S(s) E'(s) W(s)=S(s)^2 H'(s) W(s)$ (e.g., take the derivative of $S(s)H(s)P(s)=0$), but there's this extra $S(0)W'(0)$ term that I can't get rid of. Where did things go wrong?

**EDIT**. To make notations a little more transparent, $S(s)$ is the reduced resolvent, e.g., for finite-dim, we have
$$
S(s)=\sum_{n\ne 0} \frac{1}{\lambda_n(s)-\lambda(s)}|n(s)\rangle \langle n(s)|, \quad \lambda(s)=0
$$
And $E(s)$ is the projection onto the ground state eigenspace, and $W(s)|0\rangle$ is the zeroth order adiabatic transform. Indeed, if you ignore the $S(0)W'(0)$ term for the moment, the equation is exactly equal to the solution given in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494637/first-order-wave-function-in-adiabatic-approximation/494709#comment1463783_494709).

1. Joseph E. Avron and Ruedi Seiler. Phys. Rev. Lett. 54, 259
2. T. Kato (1950). "On the Adiabatic Theorem of Quantum Mechanics". Journal of the Physical Society of Japan. 5 (6): 435–439.

**EDIT 2**. I realized that you can actually derive Eq. (3) in paper {1} just by using the Schrodinger equation
$$
\partial_1 \Psi = \frac{i}{V}H\Psi
$$
Without any adiabatic theorem. I'm not sure why the author included that slightly misleading footnote.

On the other hand, I now think that the usual first order adiabatic approximation (e.g., [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494637/first-order-wave-function-in-adiabatic-approximation/494709#comment1463783_494709)) is not **strictly** speaking a first order approximation, since the approximation does not satisfy the initial condition $\psi(t=0)=|0\rangle$. In fact, the approximation only satisfies the initial condition up to first order $O(1/\tau)$, but the approximation itself is first order $O(1/\tau)$, so it's not really meaningful from what I can understand (please correct me if I'm wrong). The adiabatic theorem is only meaningful up to zeroth order.